# How can I apply CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tags

I have a list of tags like `tag 01`, `tag 02`, `tag 03`, `tag 04`, `tag 05`, and so on...

I want to apply CSS, which puts a class for tag 01, and I assign a color, etc., to it. Same for tag 02, tag 03 and so on.

The problem is, I can't edit the HTML where it is like:

```
<p>tag 01, tag 02, tag 03, tag 04, tag 05</p>
```

I don't know if it is possible to put a class using Java, CSS, or anything else for each tag.

Please let me know if it is possible, and if yes then how it is possible.

Comment: There exist many tutorials about CSS, HTML and JS

Comment: Not understanding well what you mean. Do you want the text "tag 01" to change color or something? Or are the tags valid html tags? In the first scenario I recommend you wrap each "tag 01" text with their own <p> tag, like <p>tag 01</p><p>tag 02</>. That way you can assign a class to each like <p class='myclass'>tag 01</p>... Let me know if that helps

Comment: You want to wrap the individual elements and give them a class, e.g. "<span class="tag01">tag 01</span>, etc"? If so, you can't really do that purely with CSS. You can potentially do it with JavaScript, but we'd need to know a bit more about the HTML you're dealing with, to be able to help you write the selectors to target the content.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question. Otherwise, it is likely to be down-voted or deleted due to lack of effort, clarity, or usefulness.  You might try [MDN's web docs on CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) to learn more about CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("p.tag").each(function(){
  var $this=$(this);
  var Tag=$this.text().split(',');
  $this.empty()
  $.each(Tag,function(key,value){
    $this.append(key==0?"":"<span>,</span>").append( $("<span/>",{class:("tag"+ (key+1)),html:value}));
  });
});
```

```css
.tag1{color:red};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="tag">tag 01, tag 02, tag 03, tag 04, tag 05</p>
<p class="tag">tag 01, tag 02, tag 03, tag 04, tag 05</p>
<p class="tag">tag 01, tag 02, tag 03, tag 04, tag 05</p>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for your amazing reply but having issue,
When I use this code, it make lots of duplicate on full page and add tag one in red color everywhere

Comment: If my answer was helpful. Please confirm

Comment: Add tags to the desired tags and run that class.  i edited code try again

Comment: Still same Mr Farhad Bagherlo<br />
It's still duplicating tags and making full page with tags only